# Looking through array in json response

Tags: python, json

So I'm sending an api request and it returns this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "Check was successful",
        "exec_time": 0.708359956741333,
        "total_upgrades": 1,
        "uses_remaining": 0,
        "uses_allowed": 1,
        "upgrades": [
            {
                "used_time": "2020-06-29T22:17:21",
                "address": "ADDRESS",
                "invite_token": "N\/A",
                "iso_code": "US",
                "country": "United States"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see it returns `upgrades` as an array

```
 "upgrades": [
            {
                "used_time": "2020-06-29T22:17:21",
                "address": "ADDRESS",
                "invite_token": "N\/A",
                "iso_code": "US",
                "country": "United States"
            }
        ]
```

How do I parse the `address` inside of `upgrades`
this is my code (which doesn't work)

```
import requests
r = requests.get(api_url)
response = r.json()

print(response['data']['upgrades'] #outputs the array like so: [{ }]
print(response['data']['upgrades']['address'] # gives error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Slap the checkmark if an answer helps to make it the accepted answer

Comment: Have to wait 5 more minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```py
print(response['data']['upgrades'][0]['address']
```

Why? Simply because it's actually JSON ***inside* a list**. Use the `[0]` to access the first item (in this case, the only item) in a/the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
response['data']['upgrades'][0]['address']
```

Basically, `response['data']['upgrades']` is your `list`. What you want is the `address` key of it's first (index 0) list item.